# Differentiate API responses between hamlets and street without number

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

We intend to use the **Google Maps Geocoding API** on our website. We want to use the [Google Places **Autocomplete** API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#Autocomplete) and convert the address into (X,Y) coordinates with the [**Geocoder** API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#GeocoderRequest).

Yet, in France, some postal addresses are formatted with a **hamlet** or a small village and the city (and those are correct addresses) instead of the classical "number, street and city".

Geocoding response for this kind of addresses is:

- partial_match = `empty`
- location type = `GEOMETRIC_CENTER` or `RANGE_INTERPOLATED`
- type = `route`

But this is the **same response as a street name with no street number**.

Is there any way to **differentiate the API responses** between "hamlets" and "street without number"?
Thanks for any insight.

---

[**EDIT**] Here is an example of my issue:

- **Hamlet** query : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=La+Croix+Fay-de-Bretagne+France&sensor=false
- **Street** without number query : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=avenue+Charles+Couchoud+Nantes+France&sensor=false

Both returns the same `location_type`:

- `"location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER"`

Comment: Do you have an example address where this happens?

Comment: @putvande: thanks for your interest. I've updated my question with an example - let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - your Hamlet example is actually resolving a street: [Map Link](https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=La%20Croix,%20Fay-de-Bretagne,%20France&hl=en&sll=68.29124,-133.271027&sspn=0.491205,2.113495&oq=la%20croix%20fay&hnear=La%20Croix,%2044130%20Fay-de-Bretagne,%20Loire-Atlantique,%20Pays%20de%20la%20Loire,%20France&t=m&z=17)

To answer your general question (guessing you have this happening elsewhere where it is not the street) which is how to tell how the Geocoding API determined the partial match. If you get a route it should mean you have returned a street (with or without number). A Hamlet should show up as a `sublocality` or a `neighborhood` if not it's own locality (here in Canada this is what I have seen):

1. [neighborhood](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=north%20end%20halifax%20nova%20scotia%20canada&sensor=false)
2. [sublocality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=south%20end%20halifax%20nova%20scotia%20canada&sensor=false)

*Note though that these are **NOT** valid mailing addresses in Canada, which makes my examples a little different than your specified criteria.

To know whether the route is an exact match or a guess is where the status codes come in:

From the [API Doc's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=fr-FR&csw=1#StatusCodes):

> ```
> "ROOFTOP" indicates that the returned result is a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate down to street address precision.
> "RANGE_INTERPOLATED" indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
> "GEOMETRIC_CENTER" indicates that the returned result is the geometric center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
> "APPROXIMATE" indicates that the returned result is approximate.
> ```

I would expect that you would see `GEOMETRIC_CENTER` more often for `neighborhood` and `sublocality` and `RANGE_INTERPOLATED` more often for roads - but that is a guess, and I think it depend more on how much data they have on the location and how the algorithm ends up calculating the point.

When you do have a Hamlet returning as a `route` I do not believe there is any way to tell just from the Geocoding API returned data that this is what happened. The only solution I could think of is to handle those cases in code within your application based on a list of known problems - but I can see this being very problematic and labour intensive.

This perhaps speaks to the hamlet concept as an postal / administrative one which does not translate to mapping data at all? I tried to find La Croix here and had no luck differentiating: http://www.laposte.com/find_a_post_code/find

One more note: If the Geocoding API had resolved the Hamlet as well as the street you should have had multiple results to pick from, e.g. [Yarmouth](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=yarmouth&sensor=false) Note the types list at the end tells you the type of results returned as well if you have multiple results: `"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]`

**Update**

I needed some more examples for me and decided to look for ones which would also benefit your question. I found this list of [French Hamlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aHameaux_in_France_by_region). Trying a few I got these results:

1. Blessey: [sublocality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Blessey%20France&sensor=false)
2. Brétigny: [sublocality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Br%C3%A9tigny%20Eure-et-Loir&sensor=false)
3. Hautacam: Either fails to be found altogether or is a park and shows as a [locality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Hautacam&sensor=false)
4. La Mongie: [sublocality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=La%20Mongie&sensor=false)
5. Ham/Clergy: [locality](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ham%20france&sensor=false) So looks like there may be some which come up as localities - perhaps a size threshold - many of the sublocalities are incredibly small.

I think you can safely assume that if something evaluates as a route your result is for a street and not a hameaux <-- (and to think I did poorly in French Immersion here in Canada). Also if you get a route and a sublocality in the results it is a safe bet which is which.

Finally if you know the address part you have is a sublocality and **NOT** a street, and wish to specify this in the address I do not believe Google's API allows that. There are other [services that do, like ESRI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-online-geocoding-rest-api/index.html#/Multiple_input_field_geocoding/02q000000007000000/).I have not used them and do not know the how licencing works in detail, but it appears to have both a free and subscription service much like Google.

And just for completeness - I think I found [La Croix](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?City=La%20Croix&Subregion=Fay-de-Bretagne&CountryCode=FRA&outFields=%2a&f=pjson) using the ESRI site in the `"address": "La Croix, L'Île-d'Yeu"` entry from that list - downside is that it didn't recognize *Fay-de-Bretagne* and give a single answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look with a sample of tests.

Comment: Not a problem - I was looking into something similar when I found your question, ended up solving my problem too. If you do have some examples of hamlets being identified as routes when they are not being evaluated to a road instead, it would actually help me.

Comment: We couldn't find any result `neighborhood` in France... Yet, thanks for your answer and for your help and good luck for your project

Comment: Thanks for your update. Well, I think we are going to deal with localities and sublocalities. Thanks for your inputs - I'll award your answer with the bounty.

Comment: No problem at all, answering this helped me dig into the details of how the API handles the address parts in responses which I needed clarification on myself for selecting / displaying results when there are multiple matches and when all of the multiple matches may not include less-likely matches which are the ones I want.